# If I am replacing a brake caliper should I also put in a new rotor, even if the existing one is in spec?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-calipers

One of my front brake calipers is sticky and needs to be replaced.
What else should be done while the caliper is out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if the rotor is in good condition – no grooving and thicker than the wear limit – there is no need to replace it. If it is marginal, scored or almost down to the wear limit, then it would be a good idea to replace the rotor.

The other think you want to look at is the condition of the pads. If they are significantly worn this would be an easy time to replace them.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the rotor resurfaced if it is within spec. The problem with putting the thing back on is there is an eccentricity ground on the surface that acts to push the caliper open when the brakes are released. This gets worn down with use, so it should be restored at each brake change. Most decent auto parts stored or any auto machine shop can do it. Probably costs $15 each or so.

Comment: I have always been under the impression that they were supposed to be as absolutely true and flat as possible, as any "eccentricity" would cause the brake pedal to *pulse* when pressed. I have never before heard that brake rotors have or should have any deliberate warp at all, is this really true?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I've never heard of that in 40+ years of owning a car, either. But maybe it's a country-specific thing - the USA doesn't necessarily play by the same rules as the rest of the world.